# Keeping css points in place

Tags: html, css

Good afternoon guys,

I'm working on a small project for my job and they have asked me to make a map and pinpoint specific cities. I have finished it on my pc and I'm trying to make sure that when I load it up onto another pc (such as their laptops) that the points stay in place. I hope this is enough information for what I am trying to do as this is my first post. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

The basics of the code is:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<title>States/Cities</title>
</head>
<style media="screen">
  html,body{
  background-color: #AADAFE;
  } 
  .Vegasdot{
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  top: 246px;
  left: 306px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  }

  .SaltLakedot{
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  top: 88px;
  left: 395px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  }

  .Phoenixdot{
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  top: 333px;
  left: 386px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  }

  .statesMap{
  padding-top:3%;
  padding-left:12%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  }
```

```
<img src="StatesGIMP.png" alt="States Map"
class="statesMap" usemap="#States">

<span class="Vegasdot"></span>
<span class="SaltLakedot"></span>
<span class="Phoenixdot"></span>
```

Comment: So you need to make sure it scales correctly? Have you done any tests (resize your browser window to different sizes)? I have done this before, and it was not very fun... It basically involved me using a lot of different percentage positioning and a lot of media queries for different screen sizes.

Comment: I have resized it within F12 function on Chrome. Resizing it on my end seemed to work fine but I sent the files to a friend of my to view and my points were slightly off.

Comment: That's a good start. Is your friend's screen larger than yours?

Comment: You should consider using a library like [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/get-started/#web-apis). Another option is to scale the elements using [transform: scale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale). Your last option is to position the marker images using pixel or percentage values, but you'd have to create several media queries to get the position right on different screen sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on here.

First, `position: absolute;` is relative to its parent container. so if you wrap your image and dots in a wrapper div, you can position your dots relative to this `.wrapper`. This `.wrapper` needs `position: relative;` in order to function as the relative parent to `position: absolute;` children

Second, you will need to position your dots with percentages so that they scale with the image

Third, we apply a `transform: translate(-50%,-50%)` which is relative to the height and width of itself.  This will make it so that the center of the dot is what we are positioning, so that when the image scales the center of the dot stays the same

Also, we can DRY up your css by moving the common rules into a `.dot` class

example: https://codepen.io/tylerfowle/pen/MrwreX

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://ontheworldmap.com/usa/usa-states-map.jpg" alt="States Map"
       class="statesMap" usemap="#States">
  <span class="Vegasdot dot"></span>
  <span class="SaltLakedot dot"></span>
  <span class="Phoenixdot dot"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body{
  background-color: #AADAFE;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.dot {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.Vegasdot{
  top: 48%;
  left: 17%;
}

.SaltLakedot{
  top: 37%;
  left: 24.5%;
}

.Phoenixdot{
  top: 60%;
  left: 22%;
}

.statesMap{
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: I like the DRY part... who doesn't love clean code?

Comment: Thank you. I'll start cleaning up and nesting better. Much appreciated.